# Cloudfront vs S3 signed URL and Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, boto3

Trying to setup a cloudfront URL that is fully signed and protected.
E.g. I want an application code to be required to access the resource.

With S3 direct distribution I can do this simply with:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')    
s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': unique_key}, ExpiresIn=186400)
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to create the equivalent signed URL when requesting a cloudfront URL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The boto3 documentation has a section showing [Generate a signed URL for Amazon CloudFront](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudfront.html#generate-a-signed-url-for-amazon-cloudfront):

> The following example shows how to generate a signed URL for Amazon CloudFront. Note that you will need the cryptography library to follow this example:

```
import datetime

from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from botocore.signers import CloudFrontSigner
def rsa_signer(message):
    with open('path/to/key.pem', 'rb') as key_file:
        private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
            key_file.read(),
            password=None,
            backend=default_backend()
        )
    return private_key.sign(message, padding.PKCS1v15(), hashes.SHA1())

key_id = 'AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE'
url = 'http://d2949o5mkkp72v.cloudfront.net/hello.txt'
expire_date = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1)

cloudfront_signer = CloudFrontSigner(key_id, rsa_signer)

# Create a signed url that will be valid until the specfic expiry date
# provided using a canned policy.
signed_url = cloudfront_signer.generate_presigned_url(
    url, date_less_than=expire_date)
print(signed_url)
```

**Cloudfront vs S3**

You'll notice that the above code uses a Public/Private keypair to create the CloudFront signed URL. This means that any application can generate a signed URL as long as it knows the keypair.

This is different to creating Signed URLs in Amazon S3, which uses the Secret Key belonging to the user who generated the request to authenticate the request.

Why are they different? I don't know, but the keypair option allows the use of CloudFront without needing any IAM Users, which might be useful for customers who only use CloudFront. But that's just a guess.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that of course. But this, unlike a direct S3 URL, requires a key to be signed, with my private RSA. Is that the only way? Why is there a diff between S3 and Cloudfront? it makes no sense to me, maybe you can explain the diff.

Comment: I don't know why, but I've added text about the difference.

Comment: But the boto3 got `403` when access the file upload by the signed url.

Comment: @JAR.JAR.beans The difference between s3 and cloudfront is that cloudfront caches the content of s3 in edge locations to reduce the latency with which objects are fetched. The reason signed urls are used is because you donot want to provide the users direct links to s3 at any time. So you create a cloudfront distribution pointing to s3 bucket, create a signed url (signed url expires in minutes or hours and not valid throughout lifetime of object). You can read more about it in their docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html

Comment: @jiamo The objects in s3 buckets are private by default. You need to make sure the object when being written has public ACL and also enable the option to allow creation of public objects in the bucket.

Comment: where do I get the keypair?

Comment: @DataGreed Key Pairs for cloudfront can be generated using the openssl application. Windows 10 has its variant associated with Git. You will generate a private key using openssl, then get the public key using a similar command. From cloudfront, you will go to the sidebar menu, look for "Key Management" -> public keys and upload the public key you just created. Then go to the key groups section and complete it, using the public key you uploaded. Then you can create a cloudfront distribution to use for a bucket, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Updating this wonderful answer by John, for those that find this and see warning messages coming from the cryptography module in Python..  `signer` has been deprecated in favor of the `sign` function on the serialization object according to the documentation.

```
import datetime

from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from botocore.signers import CloudFrontSigner
def rsa_signer(message):
   with open('path/to/key.pem', 'rb') as key_file:
       private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
           key_file.read(),
           password=None,
           backend=default_backend()
       )
   return private_key.sign(message, padding.PKCS1v15(), hashes.SHA1())

key_id = 'AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE'
url = 'http://d2949o5mkkp72v.cloudfront.net/hello.txt'
expire_date = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1)

cloudfront_signer = CloudFrontSigner(key_id, rsa_signer)

# Create a signed url that will be valid until the specfic expiry date
# provided using a canned policy.
signed_url = cloudfront_signer.generate_presigned_url(
     url, date_less_than=expire_date)
print(signed_url)
```

This just updates the answer so it doesn't throw the deprecation warning, and doesn't look at security aspects of pieces in use.

Comment: Please don't add a new answer, please edit the existing answer.

Comment: Understood, didn't realize I had that option being a new contributor..

Comment: It looks like the maintainers of the Boto3 documentation copied this ad verbatim into their manual (https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/boto3/examples/cloudfront.rst).

Answer (score 0):

The `CloudFrontSigner` docstring includes this way of signing a Cloudfront URL in the botocore [GitHub repository](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/signers.py?plain=1#L362).

**Step 1:** Be sure to `pip install rsa`

**Step 2:**
From the `CloudFrontSigner` docstring:

> First you create a cloudfront signer based on a normalized RSA signer:

```py
import rsa


def rsa_signer(message):
    private_key = open('private_key.pem', 'r').read()
    return rsa.sign(
        message,
        rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(private_key.encode('utf8')),
        'SHA-1')  # CloudFront requires SHA-1 hash
```

Then you actually use it:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from botocore.signers import CloudFrontSigner


key_id = 'AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE'
cf_signer = CloudFrontSigner(key_id, rsa_signer)  # <- Use rsa_signer here

# Create a signed url that will be valid until the specfic expiry date
# provided using a canned policy.
expire_date = datetime(2017, 1, 1)

signed_url = cloudfront_signer.generate_presigned_url(
    url='http://d2949o5mkkp72v.cloudfront.net/hello.txt',
    date_less_than=expire_date)
print(signed_url)
```